# Custom Post Type - custom form in dashboard

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I've created my custom post type, let's say called FAQ. I've created it in functions.php. I can also display it in dashboard. The thing is, I don't know how to create form in dashboard, when he clicks on add new FAQ, where admin can fill field (type string) Question, and field Answer.
Once I've found some plugin that was capable of creating this kind of forms, but I forgot the name and can't find it :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've found what I was looking for.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com
ACF solved the problem. I can only recommend.